# PHP - I'm getting array to string conversion error in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter

im trying to have an edit/update module in my system. But, it seems i cant figure it out why im getting array to string conversion error. Below are the model,view,controller codes.

Line error in model

```
function updatebyid($userid, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $userid); **i get the error in this line in my model**
```

Line error in controller

```
$userid = $this->model_user->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
    if ($this->model_user->updatebyid($userid, $data)) **AND IN THIS LINE TOO IN MY CONTROLLER**
```

My model

```
function get_user_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->result();
}
function updatebyid($userid, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $userid);
    $query = $this->db->update('users', $data);
    return $query->result();
    //return $query->row()->query;
}
```

My view

```
</div>
    <div class="row well" style="color: black; margin-top: 15px;">
        <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
            <?php $attributes = array("name" => "registerform");
        echo form_open("account/edituserinfo/", $attributes);?>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="fname" required type="text" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="mname">Middle Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="mname" required placeholder="Middle Name" type="text" value="<?php echo $mname; ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('mname'); ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="lname" required placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('lname'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="input-group" style="padding-top: 15px; margin-left: 15px">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
            <!--input class="form-control" name="id" placeholder="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /-->
        </div>

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

My controller

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('include/headnav');
    $details = $this->model_user->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
    $data['name'] = $details[0]->fname . " " . $details[0]->lname;
    $data['level'] = $this->session->userdata('level');
    $data['fname'] = $details[0]->fname;
    $data['mname'] = $details[0]->mname;
    $data['lname'] = $details[0]->lname;
    $data['gender'] = $details[0]->gender;
    $data['email'] = $details[0]->email;
    $data['mobileNum'] = $details[0]->mobileNum;
    $data['landlineNum'] = $details[0]->landlineNum;
    $data['homeaddress'] = $details[0]->homeaddress;
    //$data['position'] = $details[0]->position;
    //$data['institution'] = $details[0]->institution;
    //$data['institutionAddr'] = $details[0]->institutionAddr;
    //$data['institutionNum'] = $details[0]->institutionNum;
    $this->load->view('view_account', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footernav');
}
function edituserinfo()
{
    $this->load->view('include/headnav');

    $data = array(
            'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
            'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
            'mname' => $this->input->post('mname'),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'homeaddress' => $this->input->post('homeaddress'),
            'mobileNum' => $this->input->post('mobileNum'),
            //'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            //'cPassword' => $this->input->post('cPassword'),
            //'institution' => $this->input->post('institution'),
            //'institutionAddr' => $this->input->post('institutionAddr'),
            //'institutionNum' => $this->input->post('institutionNum'),
            //'position' => $this->input->post('position'),
        );

    $userid = $this->model_user->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
    if ($this->model_user->updatebyid($userid, $data))
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Profile edited.</div>');
            redirect('account/edituserinfo');
        }
        else
        {
            // error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error. Check credentials.</div>');
            redirect('account/edituserinfo');
        }
}

    function updateuinfoview()
{
    $this->load->view('include/headnav');
    $details = $this->model_user->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
    //$data['fname'] = $details[0]->fname . " " . $details[0]->lname;
    $data['fname'] = $details[0]->fname;
    $data['lname'] = $details[0]->lname;
    $data['mname'] = $details[0]->mname;
    $data['gender'] = $details[0]->gender;
    $data['email'] = $details[0]->email;
    $data['mobileNum'] = $details[0]->mobileNum;
    $data['landlineNum'] = $details[0]->landlineNum;
    $data['homeaddress'] = $details[0]->homeaddress;
    //$data['position'] = $details[0]->position;
    //$data['institution'] = $details[0]->institution;
    //$data['institutionAddr'] = $details[0]->institutionAddr;
    //$data['institutionNum'] = $details[0]->institutionNum;
    $this->load->view('view_editprofile', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footernav');
}
```

This is the error message

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Array to string conversion
>   Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php
>   Line Number: 669
>
> Backtrace:
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\THTF.6\application\models\model_user.php
>   Line: 73
>   Function: where
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\THTF.6\application\controllers\Account.php
>   Line: 74
>   Function: updatebyid
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\THTF.6\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once
>
> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1054
>   Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
>   UPDATE `users` SET `lname` = 'Taz', `fname` = 'Vinny', `mname` = 'Paz', `gender` = 'Male', `homeaddress` = 'USA', `mobileNum` = '4123' WHERE `id` = `Array`
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/THTF.6/system/database/DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 691

Comment: You're accessing an array as a string. What's the actual error?

Comment: Please show us the **complete error message** complete with line number and then indicate in your code which is the line causing the problem

Comment: when i try to update the user's data i get unknown column 'Array' in my where clause

Comment: my bad, i edited my post just now.

Comment: I think you will find the Database Error more important to fix!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing array of user details instead of user id in update

change this line

```
$userid = $this->model_user->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
```

to

```
$userid = $this->session->userdata('id');
```

in `function edituserinfo()` of controller

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, it didn't work. i got this error

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function result() on boolean

Filename: models/model_user.php

Line Number: 75

Comment: return $query->result(); in this line in function updatebyid of model

Comment: remove `return $query->result();` from `updatebyid` function. Update method will not return result

Answer (score 1):

You are getting array to string conversion error because your model :

```
$this->model_user->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'))
```

returns an array of objects. To remedy your problem, you could loop the result 
    or if you only need the first row of your result you could do this:

```
$userid = $this->model_user->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
if ($this->model_user->updatebyid($userid[0]->id, $data))
```

or perhaps you can modify your **model** like this:

```
function get_user_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->row(); // use row if you only want the first row of the result of your query
}
```

**controller**:

```
$userid = $this->model_user->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
if ($this->model_user->updatebyid($userid->id, $data))
```

***************************************************************************************
or a more comprehensive **model** so you wont need to change your controller:

```
function get_user_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $result = $query->row();
    return ($result) ? $result->id : false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$userid = $this->model_user->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('id'));
```

In the above line you are querying the database which will return an array.

Instead set the user ID as below

```
$userid = $this->session->userdata('id');
```

Your Answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still it didn't work im getting this error
Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function result() on boolean

Filename: models/model_user.php

Line Number: 75

Comment: return $query->result(); in this line in function updatebyid of model

Comment: $userid = $this->session->userdata('id'); $this->model_user->updatebyid($userid, $data);  in your controller just write this code